# How to remove punctuation from a text?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, nlp, punctuation

I have a very big data set . I am wondering How I can remove all punctuation from a big dataset in pyspark? For example `, . & \ | - _`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace` to remove the punctuations you specified using a regex expression:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.select(
    [F.regexp_replace(col, r',|\.|&|\\|\||-|_', '').alias(col) for col in df.columns]
)
```

Comment: could you please tell me how you made this punctuation ? I wanna add some words as well. should I put them inside of `|` `|`?

Comment: `|` stands for 'or' in regex, so you can just concatenate the regex with `|word1|word2`, for example.

Comment: I get an empty `df2.show()` after applying this code

Comment: @Nagh then maybe your df is empty.

Comment: No it is not, The result is empty

Comment: Please show me your dataframe and code in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227152/discussion-between-mck-and-nagh

Comment: I have a very big issue now. when I remove something with this method it remove spaces and joined words together. can I fix it?

Comment: @Nagh please open another question and provide enough details, and please kindly don't unaccept answers if they have worked for your previous question.

Comment: I am not allowed to ask a new one. and extremely need help. the above code put space between letters. in order to fix it I need to remove one space between letter not 2 or more. Could you plz tell me how I can do that?

Comment: I don't understand. Mind going to chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227152/discussion-between-mck-and-nagh

Comment: for example I have `p r o g r a m e r  a t  w h e r e` I want to fix it to `programer at where`